# constrain self.view declared in func loadview to a partial area of the view controller

Tags: swift, view, nslayoutconstraint, self, loadview

My code below subclass canvas for drawing propetries. I am trying to constrain canvas to a specific area in viewdidload. The problem is that func loadView is preventing the constraints in viewdidload from working. In the debugg area it states Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

```
  var canvas = Canvas()

 override func loadView() {
         self.view = canvas


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    canvas.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
               canvas.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :37.5),
               canvas.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : 225),
               canvas.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75),
               canvas.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
    ])

}

class Canvas: UIView {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding **canvas** as sub-view of **view**? You need to do that before setting the constraints:

```swift
        canvas.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.view.addSubview(canvas)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
                   canvas.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :37.5),
                   canvas.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : 225),
                   canvas.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 75),
                   canvas.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        ])
```

Comment: I tried your code this is what I am getting in the debug area Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'